# How to modify this String in Java?

Tags: java, string

Suppose I am having two Strings as follows :

```
String name = "EXAMPLE_MODEL_1";
String actionName = "ListModels";
```

I want resulting string as Follows :

```
String result = "ExampleModel1ListModels";
```

I tried the Follwoing code :

```
String result = name.toLowerCase().replaceAll("_", "");
result = result.concat(actioName);
```

And I am getting the result value as "examplemodel1ListModels". But the exepected one is "ExampleModel1ListModels".

Comment: I dont understand ur Q,ur getting what u expected ,please correct typos if u have any

Comment: I could be wrong, but if I understand this correctly `toLowerCase` should convert result to lower case. Wouldn't that explain why you're not getting the original capitalized results?

Comment: it is edited by @lucifer there was a typo Example was Examole

Comment: because that was typing mistake in her question which none of you marked.

Comment: ppl  r tempted to answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the simplest way to convert a Java string from all caps (words separated by underscores) to CamelCase (no word separators)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143951/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-convert-a-java-string-from-all-caps-words-separated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine your partial solution, with the function described here:

[What is the simplest way to convert a Java string from all caps (words separated by underscores) to CamelCase (no word separators)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143951/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-convert-a-java-string-from-all-caps-words-separated)

Answer (score 2):

The `name` string needs to have the underscores replaced -- you've done that. Before you do that, you need to [convert it to title case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086123/titlecase-conversion).

After that, simply concatenate the two strings.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `toLowerCase()` method so you are getting result like that. Don't use this function.

Comment: Then which function to be used ?

Comment: @Beginner you need to find some function to convert your String to Title Case rather than Lower Case.

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache's [`WordUtil.Capitalize`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29) Method.

Answer (score 0):

Use Guava's [`CaseFormat`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html)

```
String result = LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(UPPER_CAMEL, "EXAMPLE_MODEL_1") + "ListModels";
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache commons-lang has utility classes that can help you. Below is my idea

1. convert name to small case
2. Use String capitalizeFully(String str, char[] delimiters) with delimiter as _
3. Remove spaces out of result from step 1
4. concatenate both

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code (I'm editing and paste the full code)

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class StringTest{

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException{
        String name = "EXAMPLE_MODEL_1"; String actionName = "ListModels";
        String result = toProperCase(name.toLowerCase().replaceAll("_", " "))+actionName;
        result= result.replaceAll(" ","");
        System.out.println(result);

    }
    public static String toProperCase(String theString) throws java.io.IOException{
        java.io.StringReader in = new java.io.StringReader(theString.toLowerCase());
         boolean precededBySpace = true;
         StringBuffer properCase = new StringBuffer();    
             while(true) {      
            int i = in.read();
              if (i == -1)  break;      
                char c = (char)i;
                if (c == ' ' || c == '"' || c == '(' || c == '.' || c == '/' || c == '\\' || c == ',') {
                  properCase.append(c);
                  precededBySpace = true;
               } else {
                  if (precededBySpace) { 
                 properCase.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
               } else { 
                     properCase.append(c); 
               }
               precededBySpace = false;
            }
            }

        return properCase.toString();    

    }
}
```