# regular expression replace 2 characters with one

Tags: java, regex, string

i would like to use a regular expression for the following problem:

```
SOME_RANDOM_TEXT
```

should be converted to:

```
someRandomText
```

so, the _(any char) should be replaced with just the letter in upper case. i found something like that, using the [tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/):

```
_\w and $&
```

how to get only the second letter from the replacement?? any advice? thanks.

Comment: Some languages have flags (eg. \u to convert adjacent backreference to lowercase) that let you modify backreferences, I don't know if you have that in java

Comment: If regex were an option, you would use `_([A-Za-z])` or `_(\p{L})` in the regex and `$1` in the replacement string.  The parentheses capture the letter in group #1 (assuming it's the first set of parens), and `$1` acts as a placeholder for that group in the replacement string.  (`\w` is incorrect because it matches digits and the underscore in addition to letters, and `\p{L}` is more correct than `[A-Za-z]` because it matches Unicode letters, not just ASCII.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier simply to `String.split("_")` and then rejoin, capitalising the first letter of each string in your collection.

Note that Apache Commons has lots of useful string-related stuff, including a [join(](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.String%29)) method.

Comment: thanks, i do not really understand how the lookbehind should work with the replacment part($&)...

Comment: I've removed that reference to lookbehinds since the above approach is simpler/less prone to errors etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the case conversion from lowercase to uppercase is not supported by [Java.util.regex.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
This means you will need to do the conversion programmatically as Brian suggested. See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143951/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-convert-a-java-string-from-all-caps-words-separated)

Comment: why this: "(?<=_)(\w)" and not that: "_\w"?

Comment: Please again note that the regular expression is probably not what you are looking for. But FYI, `_\w` matches both the underscore and the alphabetical character that follows whereas `(?<=_)(\w)` matches only the alphabetical character.

Comment: Yes, `_\w` consumes the underscore, but so what?  You're not keeping it anyway, and you're *capturing* the letter.  Even if you could use a regex for this, lookbehinds would be irrelevant.  (And just so you know, `\w` matches underscores and digits as well as letters.)

Comment: Well noted Alan, especially since the replacement removes the underscore which is needed here.

Answer (score -2):

You can also write a simple method to do this. It's more complicated but more optimized :

```
public static String toCamelCase(String value) {
    value = value.toLowerCase();
    byte[] source = value.getBytes();
    int maxLen = source.length;
    byte[] target = new byte[maxLen];
    int targetIndex = 0;

    for (int sourceIndex = 0; sourceIndex < maxLen; sourceIndex++) {
        byte c = source[sourceIndex];
        if (c == '_') {
            if (sourceIndex < maxLen - 1)
                source[sourceIndex + 1] = (byte) Character.toUpperCase(source[sourceIndex + 1]);
            continue;
        }

        target[targetIndex++] = source[sourceIndex];
    }

    return new String(target, 0, targetIndex);
}
```

I like Apache commons libraries, but sometimes it's good to know how it works and be able to write some specific code for jobs like this.

Comment: @immerhart It works only if the default encoding is single byte per character, such as ASCII, ISO-8859-1 or similar. It fails for any Unicode encoding. But most of all, there is absolutely no reason to design like this and the correct solution would use the same amount of code.

Comment: @immerhart This solution can be easily fixed, if you think you'll need it.

Comment: and how? instead of using byte[], char[]?

Comment: Oops, my bad. You're right, I assumed he just needed single-byte characters. Also, using toCharArray is, indeed, much better.

Comment: @DayS If you fix it, notify Brian Agnew, he'll probably remove the downvote in that case.

Comment: You don't even need `toCharArray()`; just iterate through the original string with `charAt()` and use a StringBuilder to create the new one.