# How to set button text to capital letter

Tags: android

Is there any way to set Button text to capital letter for the first character and all text is cap?

Layout:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/q1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_btn_q_normal" />
```

Activity:

```
final Button q1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q1);
q1.setText(answers[numbers.get(0)]);
    q1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){

        q1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_q_right);

    }
});
```

answers[numbers.get(0)] is the text that I get from array list.

I have tried with q1.setAllCaps(true); but it's doesn't work for me.

Thanks.

Comment: programmatically or with the layout?

Comment: Dear blackbelt, with programmatically. thanks you.

Comment: what about String.toUpperCase()?

Comment: Use answers[number.get(0)].toUppercase()

Comment: String text = answers[numbers.get(0)] ;
text = Character.toUpperCase(text.charAt(0)) + text.subString(1).toLowerCase();

Comment: Convert answers[numbers.get(0)].toString.toUppercase();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final Button q1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q1);
String label = answers[numbers.get(0)];
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append( label .substring(0,1) );
sb.append( label .substring(1).toLowerCase() );
label = sb.toString();

q1.setText(label);
    q1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){

        q1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_q_right);

    }
});
```

Code for string conversion taken from: [What is the simplest way to convert a Java string from all caps (words separated by underscores) to CamelCase (no word separators)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143951/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-convert-a-java-string-from-all-caps-words-separated)

Answer (score 2):

You can use: [WordUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html)

method:

**capitalize(String str)**:

> Capitalizes all the whitespace separated words in a String.

or: **capitalizeFully(String str)**

> Converts all the whitespace separated words in a String into capitalized words, that is each word is made up of a titlecase character and then a series of lowercase characters.